# Как будет выглядеть JS код, который выполнится ровно в 00:00?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Какой код исполнится в назначенное время, если использовать библиотеку moment.js?

Comment: исполнится тот, который вы напишите

Comment: А пользователь возьмет и закроет браузер в 23:59.

Answer (score 1):

Никакой. Исполниться в определенный момент времени может только какое-то определенное действие, а код может в определенный момент начать выполняться, закончить выполняться, продолжать выполняться.